# Execute git command which is in a variable powershell

Tags: powershell

I only try to execute this little git command in a *.ps1 file and write the result in a file

```
$git_command = 'git --version'
$git_command 2>&1 | Tee-Object  output.txt
```

It only writes this in the output.txt file

```
git --version
```

When I write the command directly in the *.ps1 everything works fine

```
git --version 2>&1 | Tee-Object  output.txt
```

I have already tried the following approaches

```
& $git_command 
Invoke-expression $git_command
```

How can I execute the variable directly as an external program and not as string

Comment: `& $git_command $git_argument`

Comment: `Invoke-Expression "& $git_command 2>&1" | Tee-Object output.txt` works for me. Am a little surprised your "Invoke-expression" didn't work for you... did you need to pipe it into "Tee-Object"?